# Обработка исключений. C++

Tags: c++, исключения

> Даны целые *a, b, c, d*. Определить количество отрицательных из чисел *a/b, b/c, c/d, d/a, a/c, b/d*. Предусмотреть обработку исключительных ситуаций и некорректного ввода. Данные вводить как аргументы функции *main*.

**Растолкуйте смысл пожалуйста, очень хочу понять и приступить к работе.**

Comment: а какая конкретно часть задания вам непонятна? вроде всё понятно описано

Comment: 1. нет проверки на количество аргументов, используйте argc для этого. 2. Нет проверки на числа - для этого есть функция `int isdigit ( int c );`. 3. конвертацию из строки в число лучше делать функцией `int atoi (const char * str);`. 4. не надо проверять на 0, при делении будет выкинуто исключение, Вам надо только его поймать и обработать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отвечу в обратном порядке:

1. Данные вводить как аргументы функции main. Например после компиляции получаем исполняемый файл text.exe. Чтобы передать параметры в функцию main, необходимо запустить исполняемый файл с параметрами, например: `test.exe 1 2 3 4`
2. Предусмотреть обработку некорректного ввода. Это когда параметров больше или меньше чем надо, или параметры не целые числа например: `test.exe 1 2` или `test.exe a b c d`
3. Предусмотреть обработку исключительных ситуаций. Это самое простое, учитывая, что в вычислениях присутствует деление, скорее всего можно получить деление на ноль - это событие генерирует исключение .